# How to do hexadecimal regex search

Tags: regex, hex, notepad++

Unsure how to use regular expression to find all occurrences after a certain hexadecimal string in a hexadecimal editor: example of hexadecimal writer = 010 editor, which I'm currently using.
Searching for: 0201010420

C Drive opened in hexadecimal editor:

```
02 01 01 04 20 (32 extra bytes any)
```

Example:

```
**02 01 01 04 20** 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
'''

^^^ -> CTRL + F -> regular expression > ????
How do I use regex to search for that occurrence of 02 01 01 04 20 and to grab the next 64 or more specifically say (32 bytes) and to find all occurrences of that. I want to do this to copy it to a text editor for use.
```

Answer (score 0):

I use regex expressions by puting '\x' prefix before Hex Bytes (whether in Text Mode or Hex Mode).

I found some description on manual page:

```
Matching Hex Bytes

When searching for hex bytes use the syntax '\xHH' to denote a hex byte where HH is the byte to find. 
This syntax must be used for regular expressions even when the Find type is set to Hex Bytes in the Find Bar. 

For example, to search for the bytes '3F 4D ?? 0F' use the regular expression:

    \x3F\x4D.\x0F
```

Be careful that '.' represents one Byte (not one character).

For more details, please refer to the link here [010editor-manual-RegularExpressions](https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/manual/RegularExpressions.htm)